# Python symbolic integration

Tags: python, sympy, symbolic-integration

I am using symbolic integration to integrate a combined function of circular function and power function.

```
from sympy import *
import math 
import numpy as np
t = Symbol('t')
integrate(0.000671813*(7/2*(1.22222222+sin(2*math.pi*t-math.pi/2))-6)**0.33516,t)
```

However, when I finished input, it gives me an odd result:

```
0.000671813*Integral((3.0*sin(6.28318530717959*t - 1.5707963267949) - 2.33333334)**0.33516, t)
```

Why does this result contain `Integral()`? I checked online other functions and there is no `Integral()` in them.

Comment: What exactly is odd about this?

Comment: Does it mean the part within Intergral() is the solution? Coz I checked online of other functions, there is no Integral() in them. @cricket_007

Comment: I don't know what result you expected

Comment: Let me put it this way. integrate (x**2, x) gives the results of (x**3)/3. So I think my integration result would be the same. Excuse me that I am pretty new to Python, I probably interpret the result wrong. Does it mean my result equals to 0.000671813*(3.0*sin(6.28318530717959*t - 1.5707963267949) - 2.33333334)**0.33516? @cricket_007 thx for your reply.

Comment: I've been out of school too long to think about integrals. I'm fairly sure that the `sin()` should at least become a `cos()`, though, so I don't really know. I'd try some simpler integrations and see what happens

Comment: thx, dude. The issue here is the power. Without it, the solution would be fairly straightforward.@cricket_007

Answer (score 1):

An unevaluated `Integral` answer means that SymPy was unable to compute the integral.

Answer (score 1):

Essentially you are trying to integrate a function that looks like

```
(sin(t) + a)**0.33516
```

where `a` is a constant number.

In general such an integration is not possible to express in elementary functions; see, for example, http://www.sosmath.com/calculus/integration/fant/fant.html,
especially the sentence on Chebyshev's theorem.